# Location of gradle binary on Android Studio Install (Linux)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Where does a standard Android Studio install under linux place the gradle executable?

I want to run it from the cmd line, but can't find it to add to my PATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Android Studio uses a Gradle wrapper. You can find the `gradlew` file in the project root. Check [this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Getting-Started-with-Gradle#intro-to-the-gradle-wrapper)

If you want you can install your own Gradle version and use it by command line. In that case you can tell Android Studio to use that version instead of the wrapper

Comment: I took a look at the gradlew script, can't see an obvious call to a gradle exe in there - maybe its running a java implementation of gradle then , i.e. the last line in the script? If I install gradle how do you get android studio to use that instead. I don't want to inadvertently break anything by having two gradles

Comment: maybe I should just read this - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: The same is for Windows.